# Can a hardware be used simultaneously by two pieces of software

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a requirement for video calling and recognising air wave gesture at the same time.

I'll use **Twillo** for video calling and **Nanogest** for recognising air wave gesture.

I asked to the Nanogest support, they say, it can be used simultaneously but I want to verify at my end before I make purchase of the Naogest API.

**Question:** How can a single hardware be used for two things if there is no switching? Like for a system processor, it has to switch jobs to do accommodate different services running in parallel.

Comment: All that's required is for both libraries to be able to access the video frames.

Comment: That means it's quite possible, isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely.  I know nothing about those libraries you mention, but it's theoretically possible that they will work together.

Comment: Thanks for the update "Avi". I'm in talk with both the guys, I'll update here once I reach to the level of conclusion.